# Let $G$ be a group of order 24 and suppose $n_2(G) > 1 \ \ and \ \ n_3(G) > 1$ . Then $G \cong S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

My attempt is :

Since $n_3 > 1$ and $n_3 \equiv 1 \ \ mod \ \ 3 $ and divides 8, then the only possibilty is $n_3 = 4$ and thus $| G:N| = 4$, where $N = N_G(P)$ and $P \in Syl_3(G)$. Then $G/K $ is isomorphic to subgroup of $S_4$, where $K = \cap_{g\in G} N^g$.

We need to show that $K = 1$

Since $|G:N| = 4 $, we see that $|N|$ = 6 and $K \subseteq N$, therefore the possibility of $|K| = 1,2,3,6$

we assume that $K = 2$. Since $|G/K| = 12$ , then exist a normal either 2-sylow subgroup or 3-sylow subgroup. We know that $n_3(G/K) > 1$, however we conclude that $G/K$  has a unique 2- sylow subgroup $S/K$ . Also $|S|$ = 8 Since $|K|$ = 2 and $|S/K|$ = 4 and thus $S$ is a normal Sylow  subgroup of $G$, which a contradiction .

I want to help in this arguments

> > We need to show that $|K|$ is not divisible by 3

Comment: The elements of $K$ normalize all of the Sylow $3$-subgroups. Since no Sylow $p$-subgroup can normalize a different Sylow $p$-subgroup, $K$ does not contain a Sylow $3$-subgroup, so its order is not divisible by $3$. BTW, you ought define your notation, like $n_2(G)$.

Comment: @ Derek : How can you say that  no Sylow p-subgroup can normalize a different Sylow p-subgroup. Please give me hint , Thank you for your Prompt reply

Comment: If $P$ normalized $Q$, with $P,Q$ distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups, then $PQ$ would be a larger $p$-group than $P$.